# Disable https for a single .php page on my wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, https

I have a search.php page on my wordpress site which i dont want to have https as it creates mixed content error. Not sure how to disable https on that certain page only. I searched on stackforum and got below answer:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^off$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !exp\.php$
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

not sure will it work for me! Do i need to add the above code or replace any code

Comment: Fix the mixed content error, that's the only solution for your problem. It's absolutely bad practice (and imo stupid) to disable HTTPS on one page because it got mixed contents. You are just too lazy to fix the real problem. I'm glad when HTTPS gets enforced.

Comment: Website uses iframe to display content from other website. I am learning to resolve mixed content error as the page doesn't show the result as needed. Being a non technical person, I am trying my best to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/yourfile.php$
RewriteRule (.*) http://yoursite.com/yourfile.php [R = 301,L]
```

Add this code at the bottom of your htaccess it should work.

Comment: Hi,
I added the above code in my htaccess file but received 500 inetrnal server error
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/yourfile.php$
RewriteRule (.*) http://yoursite.com/yourfile.php [R = 301,L]
</IfModule>

Comment: If your htaccess code contains any rule that have L you should delete the L keyword.